# JavaFX 11 OpenJDK module-info.java

Tags: java, javafx, java-module, java-11

Error:(1,1) java: module Reports reads package java.awt from both java.desktop and java.datatransfer

I'm clueless to this problem and how to fix it.

module-info.java is as follows:

```
module Reports {
 requires javafx.graphics;
 requires com.jfoenix;
 requires javafx.fxml;
 requires javafx.controls;
 requires java.sql;
 requires org.joda.time;
 requires jna;
 requires jna.platform;
 requires java.datatransfer;
 requires java.desktop;
}
```

Comment: what version of jfx are you using and how?

Comment: My program files folder consists of "javafx-sdk-11" and "jdk-11.0.1"

Comment: Can you look into the module-info of both the module `java.desktop` and `java.datatransfer` and confirm that they actually `exports` the `java.awt` module. I couldn't reproduce the error that you stated with a downloaded SDK jar assuming they have the [same modules as these](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/) which doesn't seem to have a conflicting export. The JDK I'd used is the version *11+28*.

Comment: I will check on that. The JDK version that I have is 11.0.1+13.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue. Apparently there is a conflict with java.AWT when using robot class. I replaced AWT robot with javafx.scene.input class and removed the requires for java.datatransfer and java.desktop and all is well.

Comment: java.datatransfer does not export java.awt so not clear how you ended up with this error, even if using the AWT Robot class.

Answer (score -1):

My module-info.java looks like this:

```
module Alemungula {
requires javafx.graphics;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.controls;
opens sample;
}
```

I think you miss open statement where sample is your starter file.